# Which species and group of clematis is this?

Tags: identification

[image: Mystery Clematis]

[image]

Hi! I'm new to the site, and have long been wondering who I could ask to help me identify this clematis. I've done a bit of poking around online at various nursery sites hoping to find it, but I'm a little overwhelmed by how many varieties and species are available. A relative bought the plant a few years back but she can't remember where. She regrets her purchase now, because it's such a vigorous vine. It topples obelisks and scrambles underneath the siding boards on the house. I've basically inherited it now (or rather rescued it on its way to the compost heap), and would like to know which species and group it is, if anyone has any idea. I'd love to know the variety too, but maybe that's too much to hope for. I'm fairly new to ornamental gardening, I usually just grow edibles, but I didn't want to lose this lovely vine, and want to know as much about it as possible. This picture is of the first flower of the year, which opened April 2nd (I'm in the South Eastern US, zone 8 if that is important to know). The back sides of the petals are a slightly paler purple with green stripes, and the flowers have 8 petals and are about 6" in diameter. Previously, the plant has been cut down to about a foot of growth every year, and it always comes right back in spring. I'm curious how tall the plant will likely grow to, so I can provide it with an adequately tall and stable trellis. I appreciate any help that anyone can give me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm astonished to see a large flowered clematis cultivar blooming in early April - the earliest ones usually start in May. Those in flower earlier are not large flowered cultivars - what are your temperatures like currently? When did you last cut it down? I'd add a cautionary note - images of clematis flowers on line (google images specifically) are not reliable - there are many misidentified ones

Comment: Thank you for responding! It’s mainly been between 60 and 70 degrees F over the past month, but the weather has been fluctuating a lot, and there were a few warmer and cooler days. The clematis hasn’t minded though. It is covered in flower buds and on the first warm sunny day it started blooming. I can’t be sure but i think it usually blooms at this time here.

Comment: I previously cut it down in February I believe, but it was already starting to put out new shoots.

Comment: February this year or last year?

Comment: February of this year

Comment: Why are the answers to this question being deleted? I answered it a while back then noticed that my answer had been removed. I thought my answer may have been insufficient, but precise identification of this hybrid Clematis is not probable. Someone else answered it two or three days ago with an even shorter answer, now that answer is gone as well. Can the original poster remove answers if they edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Clematis Lanuginosa Lindl.  The positive identification can be made by examining the color of the stamens that on a Lanuginosa is purpur and white.
It belongs to the family Ranunculaceae.
To read more about this beautiful vine you can search Biolib.cz

Answer (score -1):

I believe it s Clematis 'Jackmanii. I grew it for many years and it was and still is my favorite!

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a bit more information: Why is this a C. jackmanii? How can a gardener recognize it? What are the characteristics? You can always [edit] your post to include more details.